# Trying to convert Json to Dart but its giving me 3 errors

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to convert JSON response to dart but over 3 error. I convert the Json from online website https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

the errors says : The method 'toJson' isn't defined for the type 'List'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toJson'.

the code :

```
class RedZoneModel {
    bool? status;
    List<Data>? data;

    RedZoneModel({this.status, this.data});

    RedZoneModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        status = json['status'];
        if (json['data'] != null) {
            data = <Data>[];
            json['data'].forEach((v) { data!.add(new Data.fromJson(v)); });
        }
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['status'] = this.status;
        if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
        return data;
    }
}

class Data {
    int? id;
    String? areaName;
    Geojson? geojson;
    String? createdAt;
    String? updatedAt;

    Data({this.id, this.areaName, this.geojson, this.createdAt, this.updatedAt});

    Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        id = json['id'];
        areaName = json['area_name'];
        geojson = json['geojson'] != null ? new Geojson.fromJson(json['geojson']) : null;
        createdAt = json['created_at'];
        updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['id'] = this.id;
        data['area_name'] = this.areaName;
        if (this.geojson != null) {
      data['geojson'] = this.geojson!.toJson();
    }
        data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
        data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
        return data;
    }
}

class Geojson {
    String? type;
    List<List>? coordinates;

    Geojson({this.type, this.coordinates});

    Geojson.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        type = json['type'];
        if (json['coordinates'] != null) {
            coordinates = <List>[];
            json['coordinates'].forEach((v) { coordinates!.add(new List.fromJson(v)); }); // ! Error at List.fromJson(v)
        }
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['type'] = this.type;
        if (this.coordinates != null) {
      data['coordinates'] = this.coordinates!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList(); // ! Error at v.toJson()
    }
        return data;
    }
}

class Coordinates {


     Coordinates({ }); // ! Error at Coordinates({ });

    Coordinates.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        return data;
    }
}
```

and this is the response :

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "area_name": "Surian",
            "geojson": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -1.2453052,
                            460.8429751
                        ],
                        [
                            -1.2200768,
                            460.9066456
                        ],
                        [
                            -1.2564606,
                            460.9423423
                        ],
                        [
                            -1.2940451,
                            460.8711205
                        ],
                        [
                            -1.2453052,
                            460.8429751
                        ],
                        [
                            -1.2940451,
                            460.8711205
                        ],
                        [
                            -1.2453052,
                            460.8429751
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "created_at": "2022-08-29T14:30:10.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-12-19T18:30:10.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "area_name": "test edit",
            "geojson": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            123,
                            123
                        ],
                        [
                            123,
                            123
                        ],
                        [
                            123,
                            123
                        ],
                        [
                            123,
                            123
                        ],
                        [
                            123,
                            123
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "created_at": "2022-08-29T15:43:35.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-12-20T08:28:00.000000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: On which line are you getting your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really use online generators that convert JSON to Dart objects.
Instead, learn about [json and serialization](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json). You can use dart packages such as [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) and [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) to generate the encoding boilerplate for your JSON response.

Here is sample json to Dart object converter for your json response above:

```
class Data {
  const Data({
    required this.id,
    required this.area_name,
    required this.geojson,
    required this.created_at,
    required this.updated_at,
  });

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        id: json['id'] as int,
        area_name: json['area_name'] as String,
        geojson: GeoJson.fromJson(json['geojson'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
        created_at: DateTime.parse(json['created_at'] as String),
        updated_at: DateTime.parse(json['updated_at'] as String),
      );

  final int id;
  final String area_name;
  final GeoJson geojson;
  final DateTime created_at;
  final DateTime updated_at;
}

class GeoJson {
  const GeoJson({
    required this.type,
    required this.coordinates,
  });

  factory GeoJson.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GeoJson(
        type: json['type'] as String,
        coordinates: (json['coordinates'] as List<dynamic>)
            .map((e) => Polygon.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
            .toList(),
      );

  final String type;

  final List<Polygon> coordinates;
}

class Polygon {
  const Polygon({
    required this.lat,
    required this.lang,
  });

  /// Creates a Polygon from Json map
  factory Polygon.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Polygon(
        lat: json['lat'] as num,
        lang: json['lang'] as num,
      );

  final num lat;
  final num lang;
}
```

Comment: okay sir, i will try your suggestion Thankyou